# User not found exception when using Refresh Token for custom Auth Provider

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I've combination of Jdbc authentication provider and custom authentication provider configured in Authorization server. The code snippet is shown as below.

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private List<AuthenticationProvider> providers;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/webjars/**").antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login","/oauth/authorize")
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout().permitAll()
            .and()
                .csrf().disable().cors().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
        .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password,enabled from tbl_users where username = ?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role as authority from tbl_user_roles where username = ?");
        if(providers !=null && !providers.isEmpty()) {
            providers.stream().forEach(auth::authenticationProvider);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

**AuthServerConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AuthorizationServerProperties.class)
@Import({AuthorizationServerTokenServicesConfiguration.class})
public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private AccessTokenConverter tokenConverter;


    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).userDetailsService(userDetailsService).reuseRefreshTokens(false);
        if(tokenConverter != null) {
            endpoints.accessTokenConverter(tokenConverter);
        }
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }

}
```

**CustomAuthProvider.java**

```
@Configuration
@Order(103)
public class CustomAuthProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();
        if("kp_user".equals(username) && "password".equals(password)) {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")));
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}
```

The authentication and get new access token using refresh token works fine for users which are registered in database.

when I authenticate the user which is present in custom authentication provider, I'm able to authenticate and get new access token and refresh token

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/oauth/token \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50XzE6c2VjcmV0' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'username=kp_user&password=password&grant_type=password'
```

However when I try to use refresh_token to get new access token for user present in custom authentication provider I get error `User kp_user not found`.

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/oauth/token \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50XzE6c2VjcmV0' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX25hbWUiOiJrcF91c2VyIiwic2NvcGUiOlsicmVhZCIsIndyaXRlIiwidHJ1c3QiXSwiYXRpIjoiOTNmNDJkNWUtZDBkMy00YjgzLThkYjYtZDA1NTdhNmJkOWNhIiwiZXhwIjoxNTY1MDE0OTA3LCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJST0xFX1VTRVIiXSwianRpIjoiMzM4MmEzYzctNzYwMi00YmY5LTk5YWItYjM2MTg5YmNiNzNkIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiY2xpZW50XzEifQ.KmB1vz4lIQYySkeQKR0HOyJEVepl-Z5R6LHJu3Zc7CA'
```

I am not sure I need to customize `DefaultTokenServices`, the source code can be found [here](https://github.com/kprasad99/k-auth-server.git).

Comment: I think, at this line: `if("kp_user".equals(username) && "password".equals(password)) {` you have no password. Add a breakpoint at this line to check the value of `password`.

Comment: @dur When grant_type is password, and I pass username and password, I'm able to generate access token, however the issue occurs when refresh_token grant_type in which case custom auth provider is never called

Comment: Do you mean that your provider isn't called for the refresh token at all?

Comment: @dur yes. It calls PreAuthenticatedProvider which uses UserDetailsService of Database only(anyway I don't have userdetailsSevice for custom auth provider), not sure why refresh token needs userDetailsService again.